# Неправильное отображение bootstrap + fontawesome

Tags: html, bootstrap, fontawesome

Не корректно отображается страница после того, как добавляю иконки font awesome

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i><span class="sr-only">(current)</span> главная</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-comments">&nbsp;форум</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-comments">&nbsp;техноты<span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">главная</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">форум</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">техноты</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">новости</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">встречи</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">партнеры</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">контакты</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i>&nbsp;новости<span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">главная</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">форум</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">техноты</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">новости</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">встречи</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">партнеры</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">контакты</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-car"></i>&nbsp;встречи</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-usd"></i>&nbsp;партнеры</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>&nbsp;контакты</a></li>
                </ul>
                <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                </form>

            </div>
```

Кто-то сталкивался с подобным? 
Скрин: [image: Какая-то хрень...]

Comment: Как раз сегодня с таким столкнулась, а оказалось, что забыла какой-то из закрывающих тэгов. То ли </i>, то ли </span>, не помню точно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте закрывающий тэг `</i>` в строках:

```
<li class="active"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i><span class="sr-only">(current)</span> главная</a></li>

<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-comments"></i>&nbsp;техноты<span class="caret"></span></a>
```

:)

Comment: Да, спасибо. Куча времени убита на фигню... (

Comment: Не расстраивайтесь. Так оно обычно и бывает :D